# Bounded functions are Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $D=\{(t,x)\in\mathbb(R) : |t|<a, |x|<b; a,b\in\mathbb{r}\}$ and $f:\mathbb{R^2}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$, continuous in D with $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ unbounded in D. If for some $x,y\in\mathbb{R}, |f(t,x)-f(t,y)|\leq 2b^{n}, n\geq0 $, then under which conditions - if any - we may assume that $f$ is Lipschitz?

I am, thankful, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None. Consider the map $f(t,x)=\sqrt{|t|+|x|}$.